# PostgreSQL Get a random datetime/timestamp between two datetime/timestamp

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

The title is pretty much explicit, my question is if i get two dates with hour:

- 01-10-2014 10:00:00
- 01-20-2014 20:00:00

Is it possible to pick a random datetime between these two datetime ?

I tried with the random() function but i don't really get how to use it with datetime

Thanks

Matthiew

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can do almost everything with the [date/time operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
select timestamp '2014-01-10 20:00:00' +
       random() * (timestamp '2014-01-20 20:00:00' -
                   timestamp '2014-01-10 10:00:00')
```

Comment: @BenjaminPeter the last difference was needed, because the original question operates with min/max. But if you have min + length, you can just add `random() * interval '<length>'` at the end (in your case `random() * interval '3 days'`).

Comment: If you don't need a specific min/max value you can use the min/max value of timestamp. In MySql the min value for timestamp is `1970-01-01 00:00:01` and the max `2038-01-19 03:14:07`. Assuming the range in postgresql is the same you could use `select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:01' + random() * (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:01' - timestamp '2038-01-19 03:14:07')` to make sure your timestamp is always within the supported range.

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `10:00:00` instead of `20:00:00`?

Comment: You can also use INTERVAL, `select timestamp '2014-01-10 20:00:00' + INTERVAL '10 days';` or '250 hours' for OP's scenario

Answer (score 34):

I adapted @pozs answer, since I didn't have timestamps to go off of.

`90 days` is the time window you want and the `30 days` is how far out to push the time window. This is helpful when running it via a job instead of at a set time.

```
select NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days';
```

Comment: can be optimized into: `select NOW() + (random() * (interval '90 days')) + '30 days';`

Answer (score 7):

You could build the timestamp from a random integer (unix stamp), e.g.:

```
select timestamp 'epoch' + (
          extract('epoch' from timestamp '2014-10-01 10:00:00')
        + random() * (
                     extract('epoch' from timestamp '2014-20-01 20:00:00')
                   - extract('epoch' from timestamp '2014-10-01 10:00:00')
       )) * interval '1 second'
```

Wrap it in an SQL function if you use it often, as it's not very readable even after attempting to format it somewhat.

Another way to do it would be to use `generate_series()` from the start date to the end date, ordered by random(), but that would make things very slow with larger date intervals so you'll be better off with the above approach.

Comment: Matthiew, did you end up using this solution? You only commented here, but the other one got marked as accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

The formula is
`SELECT random() * (b - a) + a;`
where `a` is the smallest number and `b` is the largest number that you want to generate a random number for.

```sql
SELECT random() * (timestamp '2023-09-01 20:00:00' - timestamp '2023-09-01 10:00:00') + timestamp '2023-09-01 10:00:00';
```

or

```sql
SELECT random() * ('2023-09-01 20:00:00'::timestamp - '2023-09-01 10:00:00'::timestamp) + '2023-09-01 10:00:00'::timestamp;
```