# PostgreSQL Get random value between two timestamps with hours constraint

Tags: random, postgresql-10, sql-timestamp

*Using: PostgreSQL 10.5*

This question is somewhat similar to:

[PostgreSQL Get a random datetime/timestamp between two datetime/timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22964272/2095534)

*The [answer given by @pozs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22965061/2095534) solves the problem but doesn't let me constraint the hours within random timestamp returned.* I'd say this is an extention of this issue.

**Task**

The difference is that I need to get a **random** timestamp between two timestamps, but the **hour** in the output value **has to be between `10:00:00` and `18:00:00`**.

**My attempt**

I've been trying to do it time efficiently, but for now have only come up with the idea of storing different parts of: date, time and miliseconds and then combining them with 3 selects using `ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1`. This is, however, far from a fast solution.

`tmp_data` holds dates, `tmp_time` holds time and `tmp_ms` holds miliseconds, which I add together using a function to get proper output:

```
  (SELECT data FROM tmp_data ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1) 
+ (SELECT czas FROM tmp_time WHERE czas BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '18:00:00' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1) 
+ (SELECT ms FROM tmp_ms ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1)
```

This get's the job done, but requires some time due to 3 selects to precomputed tables with sorting (and it will need to be computed for every row).

**Sample data / Explanation**

Given time constraints of:

- start_timestamp => `2016-01-01 10:00:00`
- end_timestamp => `2017-12-31 18:00:00`

Let's generate random timestamp in terms of every part but hour (hour has to be between 10 and 18).

**Sample output** - randomly generated

```
 2016-09-12 11:54:59.4919
 2016-01-10 10:39:03.626985
 2016-01-03 15:58:19.599016
 2016-04-11 10:05:07.527829
 2016-07-04 12:57:33.125333
 2017-12-15 14:17:46.975731
 2016-10-04 16:55:01.701048
 2016-09-26 13:36:59.71145
 2017-09-06 17:25:09.426963
 2016-09-08 17:08:00.917743
```

Each hour here is between 10 and 18, but every other part of the timestamp is random.

Comment: Should the date part be completely random or is it given or is it random between the start and end timestamp?

Comment: As mentioned in **Task** it's random between start and end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the output from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22965061/2095534) to `date` type, then adding `10:00:00` time (lower hour constraint) and `random` interval of up to 8 hours (upper hour constraint) does this pretty quickly:

```
select 
  date (timestamp '2016-01-01' + 
        random() * (timestamp '2017-12-31' - timestamp '2016-01-01'))
 + time '10:00:00' 
 + random() * INTERVAL '8 hours';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the timestamps into seconds with `EXTRACT(epoch FROM <YOUR TIMESTAMP>)` you can do this:

1. `random()` gives a value between 0 and `1`
2. if you multiply the random value with the timestamps difference you get the possible range (for 10 to 18 hours the range would be between 0 and 8 hours)
3. add a starting point to the range shifts the calculated value to a value between you starting and you end point. Now you have your expected random timestamp in seconds
4. convert the seconds back to the Postgres timestamp with `to_timestamp`
5. do this 2 times: One time to get the random date and one time to get the random time.
6. add both timestamps (one casted into date, one into time).

The query

```
WITH timestamps AS (

    SELECT 
        EXTRACT(epoch FROM start::time) start_time,
        EXTRACT(epoch FROM "end"::time) end_time,
        EXTRACT(epoch FROM start::date) start_date,
        EXTRACT(epoch FROM "end"::date) end_date
    FROM (
        SELECT
            '2016-01-01 10:00:00'::timestamp as start,
            '2017-12-31 18:00:00'::timestamp as end
    ) s
)

SELECT 
    to_timestamp(
        random() * (ts.end_date - ts.start_date) + ts.start_date 
    )::date + 
    to_timestamp(
        random() * (ts.end_time - ts.start_time) + ts.start_time 
    )::time 
FROM timestamps ts
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8be7cec07a419ff2d49a078400f3274e)