# ERROR: column "event_start_adj" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently inserting/updating a random timestamp without timezone data on the columns but PostgreSQL keeps giving me the error `ERROR:  column "event_start_adj" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type interval` and the hint says: `HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

my query:

```
UPDATE dashboard.event SET event_start_adj = (random() * ('2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone - '2020-04-16 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone )) WHERE event_id = 2286
```

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964272/postgresql-get-a-random-datetime-timestamp-between-two-datetime-timestamp

Comment: That's the one im trying to use as seen on my code but it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because the result of your query is an interval an not a timestamp. You need to add the first date do the interval to get a timestamp.

```
UPDATE dashboard.event SET event_start_adj = '2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp + (random() * ('2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone - '2020-04-16 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone )) WHERE event_id = 2286
```